# Unable to use the PUT HTTP method

Tags: rest, pmml

I am currently using jpmml openscoring REST API...https://github.com/jpmml/openscoring

I have successfully installed Maven and built the  uber-JAR file.

I am also able to access localhost:8080/OpenScoring/rules.pmml using postman REST client in chrome. (rules.pmml is the pmml file that contains the scoring rules that I want to implement  )

But, I am only able to use  POST and GET methods. When I try to implement other methods, I am getting a 403 error . Please let me know how I can access the other REST methods like PUT.

PS: Apologies if I have used wrong terminology. I am new to REST and openscoring.

Comment: Why is this tagged 'curl' ?

Comment: the site https://github.com/jpmml/openscoring said we could use Curl invocations. I thought someone who knew Curl might help. It was a mistake. I removed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP status code 403 means "Forbidden". Simply put, you don't have sufficient privileges to execute PUT and DELETE methods that modify the state of the Openscoring service.

You have two options here:

- Log in to the server where the Openscoring service is running and re-try your commands. All users that originate from `localhost` are granted the administrator role.
- Implement your own authentication and authorization filter.

This information is also available in the README.md file.